# Django Rest Framework Nested Different Serializer Saving Problem

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Category and Product Models. I have created 2 serializers for each model. When i want to add a new product i send this json: {"name":"name","price":1,"category":{"id":1}} but django gives error and says that i need to specify category name too. I have already given id so why do i have to give category name too (category that has id 1 already exists. I am trying to add new product to this category )?. If i make name field of category not required django doesn't give error. But when i want to add new category it doesn't give error if i don't specify name field in json. I want django to give "name required" error when i try to add new category but i don't want it to give error when i try to add new product. If i make category read_only it doesn't update category_id of product when i want to update a product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price=models.FloatField()
    category=models.ForeignKey("Category",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)

class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields="__all__"

class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields="__all__"
    category=CategorySerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.

My solution is:

```
class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields="__all__"

class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields="__all__"
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    category_id = PKR(queryset=Category.objects.all(),
               source="category",write_only=True)
```

in this way:
when **you want add or update** use category_id field to use exist category

if **you want read** serializer return category with all fields :)